# Calculating in mysql with DATEDIFF for data in past 24hrs?

Tags: mysql

So I have 'table1' I need to insert data from 'table2' where 'table2'.'created_at' is from the past 24hrs.
Don't have much experience in SQL so any advice its welcome.

I have this query for now, but the clients using the website are in different timezone.

```
INSERT INTO 'table1' (
  col1, col2, col3, col4
)
SELECT
  NOW(), 0, table2.col3, COUNT(*)
FROM
  'table2'
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(
    table2.created_at, CURDATE()
  ) >= -1
GROUP BY
  table2.col3
```

Can I make the query to get the created_at as a datetime, get the current datetime, and count the data created in the past 24 hours rather than basing the query off of dates?

UPDATE

what I was needed in the where clause is:

```
WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

Comment: `rather than basing the query off of dates` <-- what does this mean?

Comment: So I want to check created_at in the past 24hrs, now it's checking dates(day)('2021-07-03' - 1), i want this to be something like (CURDATE() - 24hrs). Hope it makes sense

Comment: Note that `'table1'` is a string.